# Parse Cloud Code relational query syntax

Tags: javascript, sql, cloud, parse-platform

I have a cloud function on [Parse](http://parse.com). When it's called it retrieves a `PFObject` then adds a relation between that object and the user. This part works fine (Seen towards the end of the function).
I'm having trouble getting the query that selects the `PFObject` to ignore those that the user is already related to

Here is my code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("NextMedia", function (request, response) {

    var LikeRequest = Parse.Object.extend("LikeRequest");
    var query = new Parse.Query(LikeRequest);

    query.equalTo("completed", false);
    console.log("user: " + Parse.User.current().id);

    query.notEqualTo("user", Parse.User.current());

    // Also only fetch if never been sent before 
    // HERE SHOULD USE THE BELOW RELATIONSHIP
    var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    innerQuery.exists(Parse.User);
    query.matchesQuery("sentTo", innerQuery);

    query.ascending("createdAt");

    query.first({

        success: function (object) {
            // Successfully retrieved the object.
            console.log("Got 1 object: " + object.get('mediaId'));

            // Record that the user has been sent it
            var user = Parse.User.current();
            var relation = object.relation("sentTo"); // RELATION ADDED HERE

            relation.add(user);
            object.save();

            response.success(object);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);

            response.error("Error getting next mediaId");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm sure i'm just not understanding how the relation query syntax works.

Comment: On your LikeRequest class do you have a user column? I'm not understanding query.notEqualTo("user", Parse.User.current());

Comment: In the bottom section where it adds the Relation, that's adds a many to many user column.

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Have you tried something like this:
    var innerQuery = LikeRequest.relation("sendTo").query();
    innerQuery.exists(Parse.User);

Comment: I'm away for a few days now, so will try when I get back. Thanks

Comment: This gives error `Object function (){a.apply(this,arguments)} has no method 'relation'`

Comment: Hmm, I just tried with just `query.notEqualTo("sentTo", Parse.User.current());` and it seems to work. Even though none of the syntax is for relations. It must just search the `sentTo` relation for any matches.

Comment: There's a query method on the Relation. Think you want to use that as the inner query: http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Relation.html#query

Comment: May have spoken too fast there...

Comment: Only now realized this is very old question. Did you ever come to a solution?

Comment: It would be helpful if you show the data type of the involved fields.

Comment: Try to include USER Class - Put `query.include('_User');` 
before `query.notEqualTo("user", Parse.User.current());`

Answer (score 2):

This stretch:

```
// Also only fetch if never been sent before 
// HERE SHOULD USE THE BELOW RELATIONSHIP
var innerQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
innerQuery.exists(Parse.User);
query.matchesQuery("sentTo", innerQuery);
```

Could be changed to:

```
// Also only fetch if never been sent before 
query.notContainedIn("sentTo",[Parse.User.current()])
```

That works.[**Parse Query**](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#notContainedIn)

Answer (score 1):

what about [Query Constraints](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#queries-constraints)?

If you want to retrieve objects that do not match any of several values you can use notContainedIn

```
  // Finds objects from anyone who is neither Jonathan, Dario, nor Shawn
query.notContainedIn("playerName",
                     ["Jonathan Walsh", "Dario Wunsch", "Shawn Simon"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think Kerem has it partially correct but notContained in is not dynamic enough for your case.

You need to construct the [query from the relation](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html) and then use [doesNotMatchKeyInQuery](https://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#doesNotMatchKeyInQuery) to exclude those objects from your outer query.